# How to get user posts using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch all the public posts from a user's wall with my user access token. I know that read_stream permission is required for this. However this permission has been deprecated now.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-read_stream

> read_stream
>
> This permission is only available for apps using Graph API version
>   v2.3 or older.

I want to use version v2.5, so how can I do this now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**/me/feed** gives you posts published by this person.

Filtered versions are:

**/me/posts** shows only the posts published by this person.

**/me/tagged** shows only posts that this person is tagged in.

Your app needs **user_posts** permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post.

Then your app can read:

Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission.
The posts that other people made on that person Timeline.
The posts that other people have tagged that person in.

If you attempt to read data from a feed that your app has not been authorized to access, the call will return an empty array.

For more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed

**Edit** : 
From a user access token, you can only get feed of that user and his facebook friends who are users of this app. Also all those users must grant user_posts permission to your app otherwise it will return only empty data set like in your case

For other users ( who have granted user_posts permission and friend of current access token user ) feed use: **/{user_id}/feed**

**{user_id}** of friends ( who are also user of your app ) available in **/me/friends**

Comment: I want to get target's feed. "me" would return my(user access token) feeds.

Comment: From a **user** access token, you can only get feed of **that user** and his facebook friends who are users of this app. Also all those users must grant user_posts permission to your app otherwise it will return only empty data set like in your case.

Comment: Got it. Is it possible to get the public posts of a user who's neither friend of **that user** or a user of this app? If possible, How?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6I3ZrySRYE). Looks like it was possible in older version and not now.

Comment: Not possible to get posts of user who's neither friend of that user or a user of the app

Comment: It was possible in previous versions like you said but now facebook has restricted it. Accept the answer in case you have got the answer you require :)

Comment: Thanks :) Do we have any alternative to do this? There are so many restriction now. Search on posts is also deprecated. Is FB trying to make apps use their other APIs like public feed API and keyword insights API ?

Comment: As of now, I haven't much gone through other APIs. I will comment in case if I find any other way to achieve this. But most probably there is no alternative :(

Comment: I have a question, is it possible to get the user feeds with friends permission. That means for example, if I post something and I choose who is going to see the post and I choose friends. Is it possible to get this feed? Beacause now I only get the public feeds.

Comment: I'm assuming this is your question, correct me if I'm wrong - To get feeds by a friend of user who made the post visible to friends - No, you cannot unless he is also user of this app and should have granted user_posts permission

Answer (score 2):

Use the `/me/posts` endpoint with the `user_posts` permission:

> We have a new permission user_posts that allows an app to access the
>   posts on a person's Timeline. This includes the someone's own posts,
>   posts they are tagged in and posts other people make on their
>   Timeline. Previously, this content was accessible with the read_stream
>   permission. The user_posts permission is automatically granted to
>   anyone who previously had read_stream permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

That´s all you can get, there is no way to get the whole feed anymore. It does not matter if the posts are public or not btw.

You need to use a User Token with the user_posts permission, debug your Token and make sure it includes that permission: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I tried to fetch the posts with user_posts permission but I am getting an empty data set. Is it only applicable with app token?

Comment: no, you must use a user token. debug your token and make sure it includes the user_posts permission: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I debugged the token. It contains user_posts permission. Could you please suggest why am I getting empty result set?

Comment: and you are sure you try this with /me/posts?

Comment: of course you can´t get any other feed, you have to use /me/posts, NOT /user-id/posts. i mean, you can, but that would only work if the user id is the user id of the authorized user. which is pointless, because you can just use /me instead.

Comment: I am trying to fetch user posts, but it requires a permission! To get the permission I need to use the wizard which is asking for the implementation. I do not understand how can I implement something without permission, seems like I am doing something wrong. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case (fetching posts and comments from a public page) and this API did a great job:

https://rapidapi.com/axesso/api/axesso-facebook-data-service/