# Facebook Graph API - accessing User's friend's posts

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook Graph API to access a user's friends' posts.
I have read many threads discussing this. Some state that it is not possible anymore. Some state that it is possible if the friend of the user is also a user of the app.

So now, I am trying this method. User 1 and user 2 are both using my app. (let's call user `1 = X` and user `2 = Y`) They have granted "user_posts" permission to my app.  Then my app gets an access token from `X` , on `X'`s device. (I believe there is no way of getting an access token from `Y` from `X`'s device)
In this case, how can I retrieve `Y`'s posts using the API.

In the following question's answers, I find:

[question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284649/how-to-get-user-posts-using-graph-api)

> From a user access token, you can only get feed of that user and his facebook friends who are users of this app. Also all those users must grant user_posts permission to your app otherwise it will return only empty data set like in your case
>
> For other users ( who have granted user_posts permission and friend of
>   current access token user ) feed use: /{user_id}/feed

But when I try this , I get an empty data. So what is the problem here ?

Comment: did you try with an access token of the friend? it is only possible if the friend authorized your app with the user_posts permission.

Comment: if I try with access token of the friend (Y) , it works. But I can't use this access token from X's device. Friend (Y) has already authorized the app with "user_posts" permission

Comment: in that case, i guess it only works with the correct token. probably because if a friend does not use the app in a while, you should not be able to access his feed anymore.

Comment: couldn't understand that last comment. so you mean, should I be able to get Y's posts with X's device and X's token if Y has accessed the app at a close time ?  because I tried that and I can't  get Y's posts from X's device even if Y is using the app at the same time on his device.

Comment: as i said, i guess it only works with the token of user Y, to get the feed of user Y. you can always just cache it and store it in your database - but only if you tell the user about it. you should cache as much as possible anyway, to make your app faster and to avoid too many api calls.

Comment: ok. that seems to be a solution. but then I have to maintain an in-the-middle server. is there a generic server (  from facebook maybe) for such purpose ?

Comment: no, there is not. don´t you have any server anyway? where does your html code run?

Comment: actually I don't have any server and/or html code. I develop mobile apps. (IOS and Android /Tizen)

Comment: oh...yeah, in that case it is a bit tricky. you really need to think about security too, not that anyone could somehow grab the feed of some app user with your api.

Comment: @luschn I decided to go as you suggested. so I first tried to store and restore accesstoken locally. but I could not even succeed in that. can you check following question ? is there a solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041417/facebook-accesstoken-store-in-sharedpreferences-android