# facebook accesstoken store in sharedpreferences (Android)

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to store the accesstoken from facebook for later use.
For this I want to use SharedPreferences.

So, I get the string part (token) and expire date as seen in examples :

```
                final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
            mAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();     
            editor.putString("access_token",mAccessToken.getToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", 0);
            editor.apply();
```

I believe this will store the required part in my app prefs.
Then I need to get it from prefs and create the token.

```
            final String MY_PREFS_NAMEX = "MyPrefsFile";
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesx = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String accessTokenString = sharedPreferencesx.getString("access_token","");
        Date accessTokenExpires = new Date(sharedPreferencesx.getLong("access_expires",0));
        AccessToken accessToken = ???

            session=Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(this, accessToken, callback);
```

here I don't know how to form the accesstoken and session. I found a statement :

```
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(
            accessTokenString,
            accessTokenExpires,
            null,
            null,
            null);
```

but it does not work with current API/SDK.

Any ideas ?

thx.

Comment: Can you explain why createFromExistingAccessToken isn´t working? Are you getting a null as response? When you get the first access token, what permissions are you asking?

Comment: @jonathanrz it says "method createFromExistingAccessToken is undefined for the type accesstoken"

Comment: what version of  the sdk are you using?

Comment: I recall it was 4.19.0 but how can I check ?

Comment: In your gradle file

Comment: thanks. actually I don't use Android studio. I am an eclipse fan. but I remember my facebook sdk is 4.19.0

Comment: 4.19.0 is the last one. Well, my suggestion for you to not cache the access token, always ask for a new one. If I remember correctly, the facebook sdk handles the cache and don´t prompt the user for the aprovation again.

Comment: ok but I need to store the accesstoken to access the user's friends' posts. because the app will show the user posts from his favourite friends that share him the accesstoken.

Comment: When you need the access token, you call the sdk to execute the user login. You need to do it so the sdk can validate if the token it has locally is a valid one. You should never store this token.

Comment: so, you mean I can't access a friend's posts even if the friend is using same app and has authorized the app to see his posts ? what is the solution for accessing a favourite friend's posts ? at the following question, I was suggested to store friend's access token for this purpose : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955548/facebook-graph-api-accessing-users-friends-posts

Comment: @jonathanrz , do you have any further comments on this ? if accesstoken storing is not a good idea, what else can I do ?