# How to get all tagged and non tagged photos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

`v3.0/me/photos` return all tagged photos, Is there any way to get all tagged and non-tagged photos?

I have 3 photos in my facebook photos. one is tagged to me and 2 are not tagged to anybody and I don't have any album.

`me/photos?fields=images` just return tagged photos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [/{user-id}/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/user/feed)

- Get all posts to user `s profile
- Use **"type"** field to get the type and filter the photos

Filter by checking if "type" equals "photo".

[Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dfrom%2Ctype&version=v3.0) example.

> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this person, or by others on this person's profile.

### or use /{user-id}/posts

to get only the posts that were published by this person.

Note the permissions section in the 1st link.

### References

[how to get user `s facebook posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284649/how-to-get-user-posts-using-graph-api)